# Linq Lambda expression convert to SSIS

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ssis

I have some existing code that I need to convert to read in ssis c#.

```
string conRef = ""; 
manOrder = new List<ManOrder>(); 
order = manOrder.Where(w => w.Ref == vRef).ToList();
```

I believe this creates a list using the models in mvc (existing code).

How do I create this in ssis script task using c#.

I have created properties in a new class for `manOrder`.

Basically I need code to build an xml out of data from a database, (using hard coded values at the moment to test the theory.)

I get a error when trying to put this code in ssis script task:

```
public void Main()
{
    string namespace = @"x-schema:http://10.0.0.2/THst%20Web%20Service/Schema/Calls1_2.dtd";
    string vRef = "";
    bool naccount = false;
    List<Order> manOrder;
    int orderCount = 0;
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlTextWriter xmlWrt = null;
        System.Xml.XmlDocument iDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xmlWrt = new XmlTextWriter(memStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        ReadFromDatabase rd = new ReadFromDatabase();
        List<Man> manData = new List<Man>();
        List<ManOrder> manOrder = new List<ManOrder>();
        rd.GetManData(out manData, out manOrder);

        //Start the Document
        xmlWrt.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Calls", namespace);

        foreach (Man man in manData)
        {
            vRef = man.conRef;

            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Call", namespace);
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("CallRef", namespace, "");
            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Details", namespace);
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Condition", namespace, "EDITABLE"); //Database to be fed in here
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("CallType", namespace, "COM"); //Database to be fed in here
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Select0", namespace, "D"); //Database to be fed in here
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Select1", namespace, ""); //Database to be fed in here
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Select2", namespace, ""); //Database to be fed in here
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Select3", namespace, ""); //Database to be fed in here
            xmlWrt.WriteEndElement(); //Details

            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Defaults", namespace);
            //Order Date Time
            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Default", namespace);
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Label", namespace, "ORDERTIME");
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Value", namespace, ""); 
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Iteration", namespace, "0");
            xmlWrt.WriteEndElement(); //Default

            //Warehouse
            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Default", namespace);
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Label", namespace, "WARE");
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Value", namespace, ""); 
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Iteration", namespace, "0");
            xmlWrt.WriteEndElement(); //Default

            //Van Route
            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Default", namespace);
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Label", namespace, "ROUTE");
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Value", namespace, "");  
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Iteration", namespace, "0");
            xmlWrt.WriteEndElement(); //Default

            //Get the orders from the man
            orderCount = 0;
            manOrder = new List<ManOrder>();

            //ERRORS NO WHERE CLAUSE in Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections
            manOrder = manOrder.Where(w => w.conRef == vRef).ToList();

            foreach (ManOrder manLine in manOrder)
            {
                orderCount++;
                xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Default", namespace);
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Label", namespace, "REF");
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Value", namespace, manLine.orderNumber);
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Iteration", namespace, orderCount.ToString());  
                xmlWrt.WriteEndElement(); //Default
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= orderCount; i++)
            {
                xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Default", namespace);
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Label", namespace, "VER");
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Value", namespace, "0"); 
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Iteration", namespace, i.ToString());  
                xmlWrt.WriteEndElement(); //Default
            }

            xmlWrt.WriteEndElement(); //Defaults                               

            //Panels
            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Panels", namespace);
            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Panel", namespace);
            xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Name", namespace, "Details");
            xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "Columns", namespace);

            //OrderReferences
            orderCount = 0;
            foreach (ManOrder manLine in manOrder)
            {
                orderCount++;
                xmlWrt.WriteStartElement("", "PanelColumn", namespace);
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Label", namespace, string.Format("Ref{0}", orderCount.ToString()));
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Value", namespace, manLine.orderNumber); 
                xmlWrt.WriteElementString("Iteration", namespace, "0");
                xmlWrt.WriteEndElement(); //PanelColumn
            }
        }

        string strDate = "";
        strDate = @"C:\Dump\" + "XML" + strDate + ".xml";
        xmlWrt.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWrt.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlWrt.Flush();
        memStream.Position = 0;
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(strDate, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memStream.Length);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            memStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can using LINQ in an SSIS Script Task and Component so I am at a loss to understand what you need done. Could you click the Edit button and try to provide more context about what you are attempting to accomplish and the mechanics of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can use the FindAll method and remove the ToList.

Lambda expression are not used until .net 3.0 in SSIS.

so my line of code is manOrder = manOrder.FindAll(w => w.conRef ==vRef);

Thanks